# Create Pivot query in SQL Server like Excel pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I am trying to convert an Excel pivot to a SQL query so instead of extracting the data first from my SQL Server database then create the pivot table manually in Excel, I want to create the pivot query directly in SQL.

Here is an example of my [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b0eM.png) and [pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URX40.png)

I am stuck how to finish my SQL query, my start was :

```
SELECT [Brand],[Location],[Qty],[Price] FROM ShipmentsTable 
PIVOT 
(
 SUM(Qty),SUM([Price])
 FOR [MFG Location] IN ... --not sure what to add here
)
```

Any suggestions please how should I update my query ?

Comment: `in ([Austria],[France],[Italy]...)) as pvt` if there are a ton of these you can use a [**dynamic pivot**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `CASE WHEN` and `SUM` function to make it.

```
SELECT Brand,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'Austria' THEN qty END) 'Austria_qty',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'Austria' THEN Price  END) 'Austria_totle',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'France' THEN qty  END) 'France_qty',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'France' THEN Price END)'France_totle',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'Germany' THEN qty END) 'Germany_qty',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'Germany' THEN Price END)'Germany_totle',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'Italy' THEN qty END) 'Italy_qty',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'Italy' THEN Price END) 'Italy_totle'
FROM T
GROUP BY Brand
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/90e75/17

**Results**:

```
|   Brand | Austria_qty |      Austria_totle | France_qty | France_totle | Germany_qty | Germany_totle | Italy_qty | Italy_totle |
|---------|-------------|--------------------|------------|--------------|-------------|---------------|-----------|-------------|
|   Apple |           1 |            1351.16 |          1 |         9.96 |           2 |       1583.85 |         1 |     1053.83 |
|  Huawei |           1 |             744.67 |     (null) |       (null) |           2 |     207704.86 |    (null) |      (null) |
|  Lenovo |           2 |            1184.21 |          2 |      1420.43 |           2 |       3454.91 |    (null) |      (null) |
|   Nokia |      (null) |             (null) |          1 |       796.03 |      (null) |        (null) |         1 |      538.41 |
| Samsung |      (null) |             (null) |          1 |      3327.14 |      (null) |        (null) |         1 |        9.09 |
```

**Edit**

I saw your commit, if you want to get `Total` that you can try to use `with ROLLUP`

```
SELECT COALESCE(Brand, 'Total') Brand,
         SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'Austria' THEN qty END) 'Austria_qty',
         SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'Austria' THEN Price  END) 'Austria_totle',
         SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'France' THEN qty  END) 'France_qty',
         SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'France' THEN Price END)'France_totle',
         SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'Germany' THEN qty END) 'Germany_qty',
         SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'Germany' THEN Price END)'Germany_totle',
         SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'Italy' THEN qty END) 'Italy_qty',
         SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'Italy' THEN Price END) 'Italy_totle'
  FROM T
  GROUP BY Brand with ROLLUP
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c6a74df150c7df6f42c6be7b0fd63dc3)

**Result**

```
|   Brand | Austria_qty |      Austria_totle | France_qty |       France_totle | Germany_qty | Germany_totle | Italy_qty |        Italy_totle |
|---------|-------------|--------------------|------------|--------------------|-------------|---------------|-----------|--------------------|
|   Apple |           1 |            1351.16 |          1 |               9.96 |           2 |       1583.85 |         1 |            1053.83 |
|  Huawei |           1 |             744.67 |     (null) |             (null) |           2 |     207704.86 |    (null) |             (null) |
|  Lenovo |           2 | 1184.2099999999998 |          2 |            1420.43 |           2 |       3454.91 |    (null) |             (null) |
|   Nokia |      (null) |             (null) |          1 |             796.03 |      (null) |        (null) |         1 |             538.41 |
| Samsung |      (null) |             (null) |          1 |            3327.14 |      (null) |        (null) |         1 |               9.09 |
|   Totle |           4 |            3280.04 |          5 | 5553.5599999999995 |           6 |     212743.62 |         3 | 1601.3299999999997 |
```

Comment: thanks for your solution but it's not dynamic. i need to manually adjust the location each time which i am trying to avoid

Comment: What is your means? could you show me your expect result?

Comment: i added 2 select queries one to calculate the total qty and price per Brand which should be added as last column to the output of your exampe and another the total qty and price per location which should be added in last row. check it here what i added please http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/90e75/24